# inotify seems to add a 6 letter code to filenames in its output, before the extension

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, inotify

inotify seems to add a 6 letter code to filenames in its output, before the extension.

For example:
`"/path/to/directory/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE filename-HzdVai.lyx"`

or with `--format "%w%f"`:
`/path/to/directory/filename-HzdVai.lyx`

This didn't happen with other scripts and I couldn't find any example of this or why this would happen with googling.

**code:**

```
inotifywait -m -r -e close_write --exclude '[^l][^y][^x]$' ~/Routines/* ~/Projects/* | while read path msg name
do
    echo "$path $msg $name"
    lyx -e pdf "$path$name.lyx"
done
```

If it's relevant, I am using Ubuntu 20.4.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. When I create a file `filename.lyx` in a subdirectory of `Routines`, the output shows the correct name. How do you create or modify the file? (Maybe your editor/program writes to a file using a temporary file name followed by renaming it to the final file name?) Please create a [mre], e.g. add a script that creates the necessary directories and files before running `inotifywait` and a script/command to create or modify a file for triggering the output.

Comment: I suspect what you are seeing is an application that first writes to a temporary file and then renames it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention of the script was to continuously update [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/) documents matching pdf files (LyX is a LaTeX-based document processor) so whenever I saved a document it would be compiled automatically

@larks had guessed correctly and tracking move events as well showed that LyX just wrote to the file with the id temporarily, then renamed it.

The final, working, script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

inotifywait -m -r -e moved_to --exclude '[^l][^y][^x]$' --format "%w%f" ~/Routines/* ~/Projects/* | while read file_path
do
    echo "$file_path"
    lyx -e pdf "$file_path"
done
```